# How to sort rows in bunches in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-database, android-jetpack

I am working on android app, which uses `Room ORM` for DB access.
I have a `table` which has `user_id`, `username` and `isManager`.
I want to query from this `table` and get all the `user_ids`. I want the result like:

All the rows where `isManager` is true should come first and and should be alphabetically sorted by `username`.
All the remaining rows should come below and should be alphabetically sorted by `username`.

How do i do that. I know how to sort in a single bunch.

Comment: Isn't it possible to first order by is manager and then order by username? Then the database should give the correct result to you.

Comment: @oruckdeschel you could be right . i am also thinking about using multiple order by .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " +COLUMN_1 +" DESC, 
"+COLUMN_2+" ASC”)
List<DataTable> getAllData();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the `isManager` column in `desc` order so that all `true` appear first and sort the `username` column in `asc` order so that data is sorted alphabetically at the same time.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + isManager +" DESC, " + username + " ASC”)
List<UserTable> getAllUsers();
```